# How to avoid dynamically allocating small objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I found that many times I only need a small `std::map` (say less than 10 keys), or a small `std::vector` containing only a few elements, and I think it's really a waste of performance to always dynamically allocate them, especially in structures like `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, there're really a lot dynamic allocation involved.

Any good advice? At least reduce the amount of dynamic allocation, better without sacrifying the ease of use. Thanks

Comment: Generally if this is a bottleneck in your code one approach is to write or use a [memory pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378306/c11-memory-pool-design-pattern). Essentially you pre-allocate a bunch of memory, then just re-purpose it over and over without having to re-allocate.

Comment: If you work with flight critical sw, you could always allocate space during initialization . Else if you need some real performance or has bottleneck you would have to write a custom memory allocator.

Comment: Have you actually measured the costs of such allocations? Just "thinking" of a code fragment as being a bottleneck is a buid guidance for changing code. So, please first perform some measures to validate the effort is warrented.

Comment: You can use [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) with vectors or  [Allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) with other containers to implement your own allocation strategy.

Comment: Dynamic allocation works *best* with small numbers of elements. You only want to put real effort into avoiding it when there are *large* numbers of elements.

Comment: The question sounds too broad to me. Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve? Talking about 10 elements then complaining about always allocating them as a performance problem... well, my guess is that your lack of experience in performance issues makes you think there's a problem there.

Comment: @rpy, @Karoly, I used to write a `Vocab` class counting the number of occurrence of string, using two large blocks of memory. This implementation is much faster than using `std::map<std::string, int>`, that's why I think reducing the number of dynamical allocation is a good practice. The above question is not specific to some project, just a more general programming question

Comment: "*using two large blocks of memory*" and using `std::map` is (quite possibly) a lot more different than just memory allocation patterns. Using `std::map` with allocator based on placement `new` and a pre-allocated memory block would be a sensible comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You may use **stack**-allocated memory for *small* size data (as stack allocations are very fast, basically just a stack-pointer movement; although stack's space is precious and it's a very limited resource), and **heap**-allocated memory for *larger* size. In other words, think along the lines of the `std::string`'s *small string optimization*.

Moreover, to speed up allocations, you could also preallocate big memory chunks on the heap, and then carve smaller allocations inside those chunks, again basically just increasing a pointer inside the chunk. For a sample implementation of this **pool allocator** technique, consider reading [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050519-00/?p=35603).

You will find this CppCon 2016 talk interesting as well:

> [High Performance Code 201: Hybrid Data Structures](https://youtu.be/vElZc6zSIXM)