# [C++]Increase dequeue<vector<T>> cache coherence

Tags: c++, caching, deque

Inside a program where a `deque` is used to store `vector`s to allocate buffers on demand;
So after a while, since `deque` is not guaranteed to be contiguous I believe the buffers would be quite a bit scattered all around memory.

Would it be helpful in this context, to create a new deque after some capacity is reached, in the hopes of the new `deque` instance being initially contiguous, so more cache-coherent?

Comment: If you have multiple vectors, each of them allocates its buffer independently. These buffers are therefore "scattered all around" independently of where you put the vector objects themselves.

Comment: That is a good point! Do you think re-creating the vectors too would help?

Comment: What do you mean by "re-creating the vectors"? It would be helpful if you showed us some exemplary code.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create a pool allocator, is that true?

Comment: yes, @FantasticMrFox it is indeed what I am trying to do, is there a std solution for it already maybe?

Comment: @DanielLangr well, re-creating the vectors inside the deque would mean new instances with `reserve()` called for the current sizes, essentially re-allocating its buffers

Comment: @DavidTóth That may save some memory, but will not make buffers less scattered. Using pool allocator might help, look, for example, at [Boost.Pool library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html), which provides `pool_allocator`.

Comment: That sounds nice, thank you! I don't suppose there is a std solution for that? This question btw is recommending the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378306/c11-memory-pool-design-pattern

Comment: There is a simple pool allocator along with others [here](https://github.com/mtrebi/memory-allocators).